# How to understand the meaning of a part of this contract

Tags: ethereum

I have this command, I don't know what it means:

`startUNIX = block.timestamp.add(365 days);`

Full code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`block.timestamp` is a read-only global variable returning the datetime of when the block exeucting this function was mined.

The `add()` function is most likely from the [SafeMath](https://github.com/ConsenSysMesh/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) library added through the "[using for](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html#using-for)" expression. Example:

```
library Safemath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
        // ...
    }
}

contract MyContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
}
```

`days` is a Solidity [unit](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/units-and-global-variables.html#time-units), effectively just calculating the amount of seconds from the number of days, so it's easier to calculate time difference.